# F# deedle transform Series<string, obj> to Series<string, float>?

Tags: f#, deedle

If I get a `row` of `Frame` by using the `.Rows.[rowIndex]` operation, `Deedle` will return me an `Object Series`. Sometimes I know this only contains `float`. How do i convert all the `obj` into `float` series in on shot?

Comment: This question may be simple. but such question is answered in python/pandas community. Whoever downvote this is discourage ppl adopting F#/Deedle.

Comment: If you know all elements are floats, you can use a map function (in Deedle the default `map` will skip over missing values, there is also a separate function `trymap` which can handle exceptions). You could pass something like `(fun x -> x :?> float)` as the map function.

Comment: @jpe, I think you should write this comment as an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Deedle series are generic, so ideally it should be possible to get a float series right away. But as the reasons why you get a series of Objects is not clear, you can still convert the values to floats by mapping an appropriate type casting function:

```
#load @"..\packages\Deedle.1.2.4\Deedle.fsx"

open Deedle
open System

// Let's prepare a sample series
let keys   = ["1";"2";"3"]
let values = [1.1 :> Object;1.2 :> Object;1.3 :> Object]
let series = Series(keys, values)

// Now apply the map taking the Series<string,System.Object> series to Series<string,float>
series |> Series.map (fun _ v -> v :?> float)

// as @Foggy Finder pointed out, there is a convenience function to only map values
series |> Series.mapValues (fun v -> v :?> float)

// Alternatively, use the tryMap function that takes the Series<int,Object> series
// to Series<int,TryValue<float>>
series |> Series.tryMap (fun _ v -> v :?> float)
```

The type of the `Series.map` function is  `(('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> Series<'a,'b> -> Series<'a,'c>) when 'a : equality`. This means that the first argument of the mapping function is the key which we ignore using the underscore as it is not needed to make the type cast. As Foggy Finder pointed out, there is a convenience function `Series.mapValues` that hides the keys.

Comment: I will add that there is a Series.mapValues